# Proving that $ab(a+b) = 0_R$ for all elements $a$, $b$ in a ring $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, taylor-expansion

Let $R$ be a commutative, Boolean ring with no nonzero nilpotent elements. I want to prove that for all $a$, $b\in R$, $$ab(a+b) = 0_R$$
So what I've done is expressed all powers $n\in \mathbb N$ of $a+b$ as a series expansion as follows:
$$(a+b)^n = (a+b)\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n a^{n-i}b^{i-1}\bigg)$$
But since $R$ is Boolean, then $(a+b)^n = a+b$, thus the series must be equal to $1_R$. There are $n-1$ terms in the series, but all terms other than the $1st$ and final terms are powers of $ab$, which should also be equal to $ab$ by the Boolean property. There are $n-3$ such terms, so I arrived at
$$(a+b)^n = (a+b) + ab(2n-4)$$
Which implies that $ab(2n-4) = 0_R$. My claim is that this can only be true for all $n$ provided that $ab = 0_R$. Thus, $ab(a+b) = 0_R (a+b) = 0_R$.
Is my thought process here correct? Or is my claim wrong?

Comment: By Boolean ring, do you mean that $x^2=x$ for all $x$? If so, note that $2=2^2=4$, and so $2=0$ in $R$. From here the claim easily follows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $R$ be a ring with identity. Prove that $R$ is a Boolean ring if and only if $(a+b)ab=0$ for all $a,b\in R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150875/let-r-be-a-ring-with-identity-prove-that-r-is-a-boolean-ring-if-and-only-if) See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221390

Comment: *a commutative, Boolean ring with no nonzero nilpotent elements* That is redundant. How could you have a nonzero nilpotent element in a Boolean ring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply distribute, use the assumed commutativity, and use the fact that $x^2= x$ and $x + x= 0$ in a Boolean ring:
$$
ab(a + b)= aba + abb= aab + abb= a^2b + ab^2= ab + ab= 0
$$

Comment: Why does $x + x = 0$?

Comment: That's one of the defining properties of a Boolean ring

Comment: It's a Boolean ring: $x + x= (x + x)^2= x^2 + x^2 + x^2 + x^2= x + x + x + x$ and then subtracting $x + x$ from both sides we get that $x + x= 0$.

Comment: It was a (multi)duplicate.